# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'response') at handleSubmit (transferproduct.js:38:1) ReactJS

Tags: node.js

i am getting typeerror here in my transferproduct.js file

```
  const { datas } = await axios.get(
      "http://localhost:8080/api/QueryProductById/"+data.id
    );

    let parseData = JSON.parse(datas.response);

    setProduct(parseData);
```

resposne getting from API with ID 1:

```
{"response":"{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Product1\",\"area\":\"gfg\",\"ownerName\":\"gf\",\"cost\":\"1000\"}"}
```

Error getting in console :

```
transferproduct.js:38 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'response')
    at handleSubmit (transferproduct.js:38:1)
```

Comment: The entire response object is stringified. You need to Parse the datas object first to get access to the response

Comment: where should i parse data?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do something like this. `axios.get` doesn't return an object with a property called `datas`

```js
import "./styles.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState<null | []>(null);

  const getData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
    );
    setTodo(response.data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Data</h1>
      {todo && <p>{JSON.stringify(todo)} </p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-lake-p3yncj?file=/src/App.tsx:0-513) here so you can test it out